# Allowing specific values for an Argparse argument

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to require that an [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) argument be one of a few preset values?

My current approach would be to examine the argument manually and if it's not one of the allowed values call [`print_help()`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.print_help) and exit.

Here's the current implementation:

```
...
parser.add_argument('--val',
                    help='Special testing value')

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
if args.val not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
```

It's not that this is particularly difficult, but rather that it appears to be messy.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

An argparse argument can be limited to specific values with the [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices) parameter:

```
...
parser.add_argument('--val',
                    choices=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    help='Special testing value')

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices) for more details.